# How to synchronize an audio on 2 or more ios devices

Tags: iphone, ios

I have to perform an action (play song at a time on multiple devices without lag) at a given point of time. My requirement is that the app should not use any internet connection. So I need an exact point of time when to play data(Audio)]

I have already tried following:

1. Play song after 5 seconds on all devices. (still causes lag of milliseconds)
2. Send a small text notification to identify playing of the song and then start playing on all devices. But sending and receiving this notification takes time of milliseconds  :(:(
3. Set time to automatic on all devices  and then checked time difference of text message passing, It has milliseconds gap in each testing.

Comment: I am using socket connection to transmit data. Data is being sent very fastly, but still i need an exact time form playing.

Comment: your question will probably be closed as it shows no effort. Also, because there are duplicate questions, it reveals that have yet to search for existing posts, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17377390/what-is-the-best-method-of-synchronizing-audio-across-ios-devices-with-wifi That said, although it's a different problem, have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357514/ios-stream-audio-from-one-ios-device-to-another/8492598#8492598

Comment: I am searching on this from last 4 days. Had scanned those links too, But no help....

Comment: then add detail on what you have already considered and why it was not effective. You'll get a lot more out of SO if you contribute effectively

Comment: I have edited my question. can you please help me now..

Answer (score 7):

First you need to synchronize the 2 devices internal time.
Apparently the most accurate clock you can have on iOS is the absolute time by doing :

```
CFAbsoluteTime now = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
```

Then you need to send this time from device `A` to device `B` retrieve the difference on device `B` and send it back to `A` , then compare the difference with the time spent in the network transaction. In this way you can have a quite accurate synchronisation of the 2 devices time. (This is presuming the network time is symmetric between request and response and that there is not much overhead on your calculation on device `B`).

[image]

From there you can easily instantiate 2 `AVAudioPlayer` on the devices set the song and call `prepareToPlay` and finally fire the play method according to the delay on the synch.
This should give you a not noticeable precision.

Another route you can take is the one of placing an `AudioUnit` on the second device connected to the microphone in order to sync the music accordingly to the first device emitted sound.

Comment: If you have problems related to asymmetric network request/response it may be worth to repeat the first part of the process the other way around (from B to A) and then average the results.

Answer (score 1):

Known Issue

When sleeping or waiting for extremely precise time intervals, timers may be delayed by up to 1 millisecond.

For reference :
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-7.0/