# How to determine if two devices are listening to audio at the same time

Tags: ios, audio

If I have two devices listening to audio and sending data to a server, is there a way for me to align the data (at the server level) based on audio so I know when the devices were listening at the same time? The audio would be scheduled so the only thing to really account for I guess would be cable network/timezone issues.

I've been looking at things like FFT and other questions related to sound but realize that I may be chasing the wrong problem or over engineering. Would it be best to try and compare frequency or use a solution like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19314488/how-to-syncronize-an-audio-on-2-or-more-ios-devices?lq=1) suggests?

Comment: What Audio API are you using?

Comment: You might use correlation rather than an FFT to determine whether two signals are similar, but time-shifted; a process that gets more expensive the longer the delay you cater for.

Comment: @coneybeare The problem I'm trying to solve is around making sure people are watching something at the same time. So before I looked into specific APIs, I wanted to see if I was on the right track with an Audio solution versus sending the time on device and using that server-side.

Answer (score 0):

Most Audio API's on iOS have callbacks, especially the low-level one. After you determine that the metadata of the song is the same (you could probably do this over bluetooth using GameKit), you could use the callbacks to determine if the time elapsed on the playback is the same, or within your tolerence.

If the devices are not near each other, you would need to send the metadata to your server similar to how Last.fm scrobbles now-listening tracks, then compare against known devices.

Comment: Sorry, I'm super new to this type of stuff. What do you mean by metadata? And how can I best capture that?